# Linux video player wrapper that remembers playback position?

Tags: linux, video

I am usually watching a couple of minutes of a movie before going to sleep and often I don't finish watching the whole movie. I'm looking for a video player wrapper that could resume the movie next time I start it if I closed the video player in the middle of a running movie.

I am not looking for a certain video player that has this feature. I rather wonder if there's a wrapper (maybe a shell script) that could use existing video players to accomplish what I need. Anything that could use mplayer (the console version) or cvlc (the console version of vlc) will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mplayer-resume](http://freshmeat.net/projects/mplayer-resume) will do this.

> MPlayer Resume Playback is a wrapper script for mplayer which saves the playback position of a file you are watching, and when you resume playing the file, will seek to where you last left off. It's most useful with remote control devices.